# Exception with custom model binding in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 RC1 API

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx, kestrel-http-server

When trying to parse using a custom model binder in ASP.NET 5 RC1 I get a `NullReferenceException` thrown within `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeModelBinder` when calling the action.

**Model binding in Startup:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.ModelBinders.Insert(0, new MyCustomModelBinder());
}
```

**Custom model binder:**

```
public class MyCustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task<ModelBindingResult> BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(MyCustomClass) && bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName) != null)
        {
            MyCustomClass model;
            var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).FirstValue as string;

            if (MyCustomClass.TryParse(val, out model))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(ModelBindingResult.Success(bindingContext.ModelName, model));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Controller action:**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetSomething([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MyCustomModelBinder))]MyCustomClass key)
{
    return Json("Success!");
}
```

**Exception:**

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeModelBinder.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.DefaultControllerActionArgumentBinder.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.DefaultControllerActionArgumentBinder.d__9.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.DefaultControllerActionArgumentBinder.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__52.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__51.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__44.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.MvcRouteHandler.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.InnerAttributeRoute.d__10.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.d__9.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Http.Frame.d__79.MoveNext()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change `return null` to `return Task.FromResult(ModelBindingResult.NoResult);` in `BindModelAsync` method call.

In [CompositeModelBinder.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/CompositeModelBinder.cs) on 64 line `var result = await binder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);` error is occuring when framework awaits `Task` that is null

Comment: This fixed the problem.  It is misleading as IModelBinder.BindModelAsync has the following comment: _"A null return value means that this model binder was not able to handle the request. Returning null ensures that subsequent model binders are run. If a non null value indicates that the model binder was able to handle the request."_

Comment: @davenewza I think the "A null return value" is the unwrapped value of task

Comment: I don't think that was the case in beta7.  Returning null worked if I remember correctly.